# Get a dictionary with saved structure of all keys in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a possible structure with all possible keys of a single field in the database, which is stored in JSON(dict) format. The structure in my task is very important, so storing in list is not suitable.There can be many levels of nesting much more than two.

This example:

```
dicts = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':{'in_c1': 2}}, \
        {'a':1, 'd':2, 'c':{'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}}},\
        {'e':57}
```

Should return:

```
{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': {'in_c1': 2, 'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}}, 'd': 2, 'e': 57}
```

The text(values of keys) is not important to me, it is better to replace it with something similar like none or an empty string.
How I can do this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how `'dict_in_c2': {'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}` is part of the output?

Comment: @GaneshTata, sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be able to handle all cases, but it covers some basic cases. 
I am assuming that

- keys that have an integer value ( like `a` and  `b` ) will NOT have any dictionary values.
- keys that have a dictionary as value ( like `c` ) will NOT have any non-dictionary values. Also, the flattening has only been performed on the keys of the dictionary at the first level, but not on the nested levels.

Here is the code:

```
dicts = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':{'in_c1': 2}}, \
        {'a':1, 'd':2, 'c':{'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}}},\
        {'e':57}
result = dict()
for dictionary in dicts:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if not isinstance(value,dict):
            result[key] = value
            continue
        if not result.get(key, None):
            result[key] = dict()
        for k, v in value.items():
            result[key][k] = v

print(result)
```

Result - 
`{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': {'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}, 'in_c1': 2}, 'e': 57, 'd': 2}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a list of dicts, which you want to put it into a single dict.

If the list of dicts is:

```
dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':{'dict_in_c': 2}},
        {'a':1, 'd':2, 'c':{'dict_in_c2': 2}},
        {'e':57}]
```

Then you can do:

```
newdict={}
for eachdict in dicts:
    for eachkey in eachdict.keys():
        newdict[eachkey]=eachdict[eachkey]
```

`newdict` will be:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'dict_in_c2': 2}, 'd': 2, 'e': 57}
```

Comment: For my edited example of dicts result is :

`{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}}, 'd': 2, 'e': 57}`, 

but expected :

`{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': {'in_c1': 2, 'dict_in_c2': {'v': 2}}, 'd': 2, 'e': 57}`

You are right, I want to connect them into one without losing any of the keys.